# Rusqlite query with SUM panics with "InvalidColumnType(0, Null)"

Tags: sqlite, rust

I have this working code:

```
extern crate rusqlite;

use rusqlite::Connection;

fn main() {
    let conn = Connection::open("db.sqlite").unwrap();

    conn.execute("CREATE TABLE toto (size INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);", &[]).unwrap();
    conn.execute("INSERT INTO toto(size) VALUES (42);", &[]).unwrap();

    let filter = 0;
    let i: i64 = conn.query_row("SELECT SUM(size) FROM toto", &[], |r| r.get(0)).unwrap();
    println!("Coucou");
    println!("Coucou: {}", i);
}
```

But if I switch

```
"SELECT SUM(size) FROM toto", &[]
```

to

```
"SELECT SUM(size) FROM toto WHERE size=?1", &[&filter]
```

and re-run, it panics:

```
rm db.sqlite
RUST_BACKTRACE=1 cargo run
```

```
        Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.0 secs
         Running `target/debug/testsqlite`
    thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: InvalidColumnType(0, Null)', /checkout/src/libcore/result.rs:860
```

If I execute this query in sqliteman, it works, so why does rusqlite panic?

Answer (score 16):

If I run your query directly in the `sqlite` command line utility, **there is no value**, the result is `NULL`:

```
sqlite> SELECT SUM(size) FROM toto WHERE size=42;

sqlite> SELECT coalesce(SUM(size), 'NULL!') FROM toto WHERE size=42;
NULL!
sqlite>
```

Since there are no rows matching the where clause, [the sum is NULL](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#sumunc):

> If there are no non-NULL input rows then sum() returns NULL but total() returns 0.0

Your `NULL` result cannot be converted to an `i64`, so you get an error:

> `InvalidColumnType(0, Null)`

If you print that error out, it says the same thing:

```
let i: i64 = conn.query_row("SELECT SUM(size) FROM toto WHERE size = ?1", &[&filter], |r| {
    match r.get_checked(0) {
        Ok(v) => v,
        Err(e) => panic!("query_row error: {}", e),
    }
}).expect("select failed");
```

> query_row error: Invalid column type Null at index: 0

#### Fixing it Rust-side

If you update your code to account for a `NULL` by using an `Option`, it will correctly execute:

```
let i: Option<i64> = conn.query_row(
    "SELECT SUM(size) FROM toto WHERE size = ?1",
    &[&filter],
    |r| r.get(0)
).expect("select failed");
```

You can then use `i.unwrap_or(0)`.

#### Fixing it SQL-side with `TOTAL`

```
let i: f64 = conn.query_row(
    "SELECT TOTAL(size) FROM toto WHERE size = ?1",
    &[&filter],
    |r| r.get(0)
).expect("select failed");
```

Note that we switched to a `f64`.

#### Fixing it SQL-side with `COALESCE`

```
let i: i64 = conn.query_row(
    "SELECT COALESCE(SUM(size), 0) FROM toto WHERE size = ?1",
    &[&filter],
    |r| r.get(0)
).expect("select failed");
```