# How do I check if a column is NULL using rust-postgres?

Tags: postgresql, rust

I am using the [rust-postgres library](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-postgres) and I want to do a SELECT and check if the first column of the first row is NULL or not.

This is how I get my data:

```
let result = connection.query(
    r#"
        SELECT structure::TEXT
        FROM sentence
        WHERE id = $1
    "#,
    &[&uuid]
);

let rows = result.expect("problem while getting sentence");

let row = rows
    .iter()
    .next() // there's only 1 result
    .expect("0 results, expected one...");
```

The only simple way I found to figure it out is the following code:

```
match row.get_opt(0) {
    Some(Ok(data)) => some data found,
    Some(Err(_)) => the column is null,
    None => out of bound column index
}
```

Unfortunately, it seems that `Some(Err(_))` is the executed path for any kind of SQL/database error, and not only if the retrieved column is NULL.

Which condition should I use to check that the column is NULL ?

Comment: Check out [the documentation for `FromSql`](https://docs.rs/postgres/0.15.1/postgres/types/trait.FromSql.html#nullability). TL;DR: Use `Option`.

Comment: The same question [but for rusqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42864066/155423).

Comment: Yes, using `fn get<I, T>(&self, idx: I) -> T ` (where T is `FromSql`) solved my issue. As `FromSql` is implemented for `Option<T>`, I can check whether the column is null (None result) or actually contains some data (Some(_) result). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If *all you need to know* is whether the column is `NULL`, you could try changing your query to:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM sentence WHERE id = $1 AND structure IS NOT NULL
```

with or without the `NOT`.

If you want to make the logic simpler so *any* error is an actual error, I'd consider changing the select value to something like:

```
COALESCE( structure::TEXT, ''::TEXT ) AS "structure"
```

so it should never be `NULL`. That should work as long as an empty string isn't a valid non-`NULL` value for that column.

Otherwise, I may have misunderstood your problem.

Comment: Yes, this would solve my issue but I also want to get the `structure` column content. Sure, I could write two requests, the one you provided first and then the one I wrote up top, but is there any way to handle this with only one query ?